# I am getting an error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isfloat'

Tags: python, oop, getter-setter, getter, attributeerror

I am following a tuto for OOP regarding getters and setters, but I am getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isfloat'

```
@height.setter
def height(self, value):
    if value.isfloat():
        self.__height = value
    else:
        print("Please enter a number")
```

Does anyone know why this occurs ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: There's no built-in function `isfloat()` in python. You should check tutorial you're following and find type of values used.

Comment: write a `simple function` to check whether it is float or not. Orelse you can use `isinstance(variable,float)`. In python3 there is a builtin function `isFloat()`.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isfloat'` check the `type` of object actually you are passing into the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
@height.setter
def height(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, float): # Idea by Siva Shanmugam
        self.__height = value
    else:
        print('Please enter a number')
```

to test if value is a float, or you simply

```py
@height.setter
def height(self, value):
    self.__height = float(value)
```

to get a `TypeError` if value can't convert `value` into `float`. Using this, `int` input and `str` with float character won't cause problems.

Comment: learnpython.org is a good choice if you want to learn python, datacamp.com, and sololearn.com too. If you are dealing with problems like syntax, types, attributes etc. you can read the python or library documentation, or check the source file if module is written in python.